# scroll down screen for longer text like stories in kivy

Tags: kivy, scrollview, python-3.7, kivy-language

I have a screen in kivy which I want to scroll as the text in the label widget is not showing all the text, just like in kindle we can scroll down the stories. Also, my MainScreen is inherited from Screen class. And as the text increases it does not show the last 5 or 6 lines of the story

here's my .kv code of that class

````
```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Label:
            id: story
            font_size: '20sp'
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            size: self.texture_size
            text_size: self.width, self.height
            halign: "auto"
            valign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.49}

            text: 

"""A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy had a collection of marbles. The girl has some 
sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he would give her all his marbles in exchange for the 
sweets with her. The girl agreed.

The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles. 
The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised. That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy 
could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl has hidden some sweets from him the way he had 
hidden the best marbles from her.

Moral of the Story :

If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship, you will always kept doubting if the other person 
has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable for any relationship like love, employee – 
employer, friendship, family, countries, etc…
"""
            ```
````

here's the class MainScreen in .py file

```
    class MainScreen(Screen):
        pass
```

Comment: Did you try putting it in a `ScrollView`?

Comment: But where to put it

Answer (score 0):

In order to make anything `scroll`, you need to use a `ScrollView` widget.

Here's how it can be implemented on the code you posted

````
ScrollView:
    size_hint_y:None
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint_y:None
        height:self.minimum_height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Label:
            id: story
            font_size: '20sp'
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            size: self.texture_size
            text_size: self.width, self.height
            halign: "auto"
            valign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.49}

            text: 

        """A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy had a collection of marbles. The girl has some 
        sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he would give her all his marbles in exchange for the 
        sweets with her. The girl agreed.

        The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles. 
        The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised. That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy 
        could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl has hidden some sweets from him the way he had 
        hidden the best marbles from her.

        Moral of the Story :

        If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship, you will always kept doubting if the other person 
        has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable for any relationship like love, employee – 
        employer, friendship, family, countries, etc…
        """
            ```
````

Comment: Now it shows a blank white screen,  my mainscreen rule is inherited from Screen

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer, but this only has the `Label` in the `ScrollView`:

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.49}
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 150  # make smaller than Label to force scrolling
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            Label:
                id: story
                font_size: '20sp'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: root.width, None
                halign: "auto"
                valign: "center"

                text:

                    """A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy had a collection of marbles. The girl has some
                    sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he would give her all his marbles in exchange for the
                    sweets with her. The girl agreed.

                    The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles.
                    The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised. That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy
                    could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl has hidden some sweets from him the way he had
                    hidden the best marbles from her.

                    Moral of the Story :

                    If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship, you will always kept doubting if the other person
                    has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable for any relationship like love, employee –
                    employer, friendship, family, countries, etc…
                    """
```

Read this [important part](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position) of the `ScrollView` documentation.

Comment: can u elaborate it please cause I tried this and it split the screen 3/4th in the white part which have the text and at the bottom 1/4th black part

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I cannot be sure what is happening. But, I did add a  `size_hint_y` and a `height` to the `BoxLayout`, just to get the `ScrollView` small enough to force it to do scrolling.